# A specific Phone Number RegEX

Tags: regex, validation, jquery-validate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Greetings,

I need to implement a jquery based validation for a text field that contains a phone number, for that I need the regular expression of these two strings, I am requesting this because I am very naive with RegEx:

First One:

```
0(5NN) NNN NN NN
```

Second One:

```
0(53N) NNN NN NN
```

N means an integer between 0-9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^0\(5\d{2}\) ?\d{3} ?\d{2} ?\d{2}$
```

and

```
^0\(53\d\) ?\d{3} ?\d{2} ?\d{2}$
```

will match. You can drop the `?` if you are sure that there will always be space characters in the places you wrote them.

Answer (score 2):

This will match either one:

```
^0\(5\d\d\) \d\d\d \d\d \d\d$
```

Answer (score 1):

Why is the first not a superset of the second? Are we sure the (5NN) in the first is the full set of integers (5[0-9][0-9]), or is the 3 in the second combination (53[0-9]) significant in some way to exclude certain parts of [0-9]?