# Javascript Regular Expression matching

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

By using the pattern from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541058/a-specific-phone-number-regex/2541084#2541084), I want to check while a user fills in the #id_phone text input field, if it is matching to the pattern, use the value of #id_phone to fill #id_new_phone's value.
This doesn't seem to work for me.

```
$('#id_phone').change(function() {
    var myPattern = new RegExp(^0\(5\d{2}\) \d{3} \d{2} \d{2}$);
    var myStr = $("#id_phone").val();
    if ( myStr.match(myPattern) ){
        $('#id_new_phone').val(myStr);
    }
});
```

What can be the problem ?

Comment: An example of the data you are trying to match would be very helpful in diagnosing the problem.

Answer (score 6):

You need to put `(^0\(5\d{2}\) \d{3} \d{2} \d{2}$)` inside quotes, and also need to escape backslashes, if you are about to use `RegExp`, instead of `/ /`

```
"^0\\(5\\d{2}\\) \\d{3} \\d{2} \\d{2}$"
```

And `myPattern.test(myStr)` is more preferable than using `.match`, because `.match` return a array which you don't really need that.

Answer (score 3):

```
var myPattern = new RegExp("^0\(5\d{2}\) \d{3} \d{2} \d{2}$");
```

You should quote the pattern when using RegExp();

Also it's not a valid regexp because if you don't want to quote it, you should use the regexp construct. E.g.:

```
var myregex = /<some pattern here>/g
```